# Can I enable Eclipse warnings for annotated variables?

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, compiler-warnings, getter-setter

I have a Spring Entity Class and different variables inside it. Eclipse shows warnings for non-annotated variables if there are no getters/setters for them.

> The value of the field Property.warning_yes is not used

But as soon as I add any annotation, it stops showing the warning because of which I generally forget to generate the getters/setters. Once I compile and deploy my app and get exception, only then I realize that missing getters/setters are the culprits. This all wastes time because of which I am trying to find some automatic solution for it.

Can Eclipse be forced to show these warning for annotated variables as well?

Below is my sample class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "example")
public class ExampleClass {

private String warning_yes;     //Here I get the desired warning

@Column(name = "some_name")
private String warning_no;      //Here I do not get the desired warning because of annotation

}
```

I am using Eclipse Luna.